# getting bootstrap-sass gem and rails to work with existing project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to integrate bootstrap into a current rails project and am having a difficult type installing. Specifically, I seem to be having a problem with the javascript. I have added to application.js:

//= require bootstrap

But I get the following error:

[image]

These are referenced in bootstrap.js.coffee and I can get rid of the errors by clearing this file out. Here are the contents:

```
jQuery ->
  $("a[rel=popover]").popover()
  $(".tooltip").tooltip()
  $("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()
```

There is discussion about loading the individual modules but it's not clear to me if I should be doing this or whether  I need to be doing this. https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass

I'd really like to be able to add bootstrap to this currently existing project. Any help is appreciated.

thx

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this.  Having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you have bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js from the [Twitter Bootstrap Docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) and then require it as you did. I think your issue is that you have yet another file named bootstrap.js.coffee. Try changing the name of it and requiring it along with //=require bootstrap.

Comment: I think you're right - I am going to try to remove the gem versions and see if I can't just bring it in manually. It worked fine with a new app but trying to move an existing app to bootstap has proben to be challenging. :-(

Comment: also make sure //= require bootstrap comes before //= require tree .

Comment: will probably just link to files directly as this is a little insane for doing such a simple task. thx

Answer (score 0):

First of all bootstrap [requires](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#plugins) jQuery. For Rails you can use the `jquery-rails` gem which provides the latest version of jQuery.

Then within your `application.js` you can load the required Javascripts with

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap

//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

As [neon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648672/neon) mentions the load order of the scripts is important. You should load `jquery` first, then load `bootstrap`. At this point you can load all other scripts in the current directory with `require_tree .` (which probably contains your `bootstrap.js.coffee`).